# How to restrict access to login route if user is already logged in and stay on the current route in angular

Tags: angular

I have successfully implemented AuthGuardService which restricts access to a protected route if a user is not logged in.

What I am trying to achieve is, if a user is already logged in and accessing the Login Route again, I want it to stay in the current route like I am on the dashboard page and I am hitting the login URL it should stay in the dashboard page, similarly if I am in Training page it should stay in training page.

Answer (score 0):

In the canActivate function you can write this

```
canActivate(): boolean {
        if (this.youauthService.loggedIn()) {
            this._router.navigate(['/yourUrl'])
        } else {
            this._router.navigate(['/login'])
            return false
        }
}
```

Comment: Its not working, if I am writing login in the address bar its taking me back to login page

Comment: where we are returning true. can you change that line to navigate to your URL

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by adding another route guard for login

```
`canActivate(): boolean {
        if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
            const currentRoute = this.router.routerState.snapshot.url;
            this.router.navigateByUrl(currentRoute);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }`
```